# MVC ViewBag: Is access to DB with ViewBag in Controller faster than direct access in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view, controller, viewbag

I am wondering what is faster. Should i store information that i queried from DB into a ViewBag and then access and display it in a View, or should i make a query directly in View. 
Controller is the middle layer in MVC so it would seem logical to me, that accessing DB in controller should be faster.

**Example:**

**1)** In a Controller i access the DB and put the information into a ViewBag so that i can display it in View.

controller:

```
EVENT e = db.EVENT.Find(id);
ViewBag.event = e;

if (e.poster_id != null)
{
    poster = e.DATA.path;
}
ViewBag.dict_poster = poster;
```

view:

```
<p>POSTER: @ViewBag.dict_poster;</p>
```

**2)** In Controller i put only the general data from DB into ViewBag and that access it in View.

controller:

```
EVENT e = db.EVENT.Find(id);
ViewBag.event = e;
```

view:

```
<p>
    @if(ViewBag.event.poster_id != null)
    {
        @ViewBag.event.DATA.path;
    }
</p>
```

- What is better and more appropriate to use? What is faster?
- What if i have a very branched DB and i have to store everything into "ViewBag.e", is it better and faster to store individual values into ViewBags and than access them in Views or is direct access from a View faster?
- What about Lists? (storing DB information into a list, putting it in a ViewBag and than accessing it in the View)

I am grateful for your answers and added explanation....

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be accessing your data layer from the view directly, this should be done in the controller. Also, consider passing a strongly typed view model to your view, rather than using the ViewBag.

See http://theminimalistdeveloper.com/2010/08/21/why-when-and-how-to-use-typed-views-and-viewmodel-pattern-in-asp-net-mvc/ for reasons behind the use of view models in MVC.

Comment: thank you. does the strongly typed view model have any impact on the speed or is it better only because of "intelisense" support and overview?

Comment: There will be no discernible difference in speed. The issue with using ViewData/ViewBag is that of 'magic strings', which impedes maintenance. See link for details.